# Parse anonymous array from JSON result with Google HTTP Client Library

Tags: java, json, jackson, robospice, google-http-client

My REST service respons with the following data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bart",
        "age": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Homer",
        "age": 42
    },
    {
        "name": "Marjorie",
        "age": 34
    }
]
```

The result set is an array of objects which I want to automatically parse with Google's HTTP Client library. Therefore I created a `SimpsonResult` and `Simpson` class:

**SimpsonResult.java**

```
public class SimpsonResult {

  private List<Simpson> simpsons;

  public SimpsonResult() {
  }

  public List<Simpson> getSimpsons() {
    return simpsons;
  }

  public void setSimpsons(List<Simpson> simpsons) {
    this.simpsons = simpsons;
  }

}
```

**Simpson.java**

```
public class Simpson {

  @Key
  private String name;

  @Key
  private int age;

  public Simpson() {
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

}
```

Now I want to query my backend and automatically map the response into a `SimpsonResult`. Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
@Override
public SimpsonResult loadDataFromNetwork() throws IOException {
  HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getHttpRequestFactory();
  GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(baseUrl);
  HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
  request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());
  return request.execute().parseAs(SimpsonResult.class);
}
```

But when I execute the code, then I get a parser exception from `com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser`.

When I map it into a string (`request.execute().parseAsString()`), then it works.

So I think that my mapping declaration is wrong?

Comment: Parsing as a POJO would mean the JSON root is a JSON object with a key called simpsons with a value that is a JSON array. Your root JSON is a JSON array.

Comment: So I can't use `createJsonObjectParser`?

Comment: I don't know this library at all. (I know Jackson). Your target Java type must match the JSON. For a JSON array, that would have to be a `Collection` or an array type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Type** for parsing parameterized classes as below

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SimpsonResult>>() {}.getType();
request.execute().parseAs(type);
```

Creating an extra class, extending parameterized classes like ArrayList, just for parsing is a not recommended. Hence your function can be written as

```
@Override
public ArrayList<SimpsonResult> loadDataFromNetwork() throws IOException {
  HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getHttpRequestFactory();
  GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(baseUrl);
  HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);

  Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SimpsonResult>>() {}.getType();
  return request.execute().parseAs(type);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you do it is not valid. The SimpsonResult, requires a field named simpsons, and there is no such field in you json.

As using generic collection types is a bit tricky in most frameworks, what I do generally for this is to create a simple list type inside Simpson class :

```
public class Simpson {

  public static class List extends ArrayList<Simpson> {
  }

  ... //you simpson code
}
```

You can then use `Simpson.List` to parse your json via annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
@Override
public Simpson[] loadDataFromNetwork() throws IOException {
 HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getHttpRequestFactory();
 GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(baseUrl);
 HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
 request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());
 return request.execute().parseAs(Simpson[].class);
}
```